# Devise Token Auth requiring current_password on password reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable, http-token-authentication, devise-recoverable

I have `config.check_current_password_before_update = :password` enabled. So when the user updates his/her password, the `current_password` field is required. This becomes a problem when implementing `password reset` because the user does not know his/her current password. How do I bypass this and still require the `current_password` when the user is not resetting his/her password?

Everything works fine other than that, the email sends, `/password/edit` returns the correct token that is only enabled for one session, but the `current_password` requirement doesn't make any sense. If I take it away, then resetting the password works, but then if the user tries to update his/her password, the application does not let permit that and gives `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'current_password' for User.):` because it's treating it as a User attribute.

Does anyone know how to overcome this problem in the workflow?

Comment: Did you crack it or still need any help?

Comment: Yep, just overrode the functionality: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/481

Comment: How you solved the problem?

Comment: You can see the conversation in the link I provided, hopefully it's patched now